# C++ class expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using  namespace std;
const int MAX_ARRAY = 26;
class canvas{
private:
    char painting[MAX_ARRAY][MAX_ARRAY];
    char fileName[10];
public:
    canvas(){
        fileName = "zzz.txt";
    }

};
```

But the **fileName = "zzz.txt"** is giving syntax error that is

```
Expression must be a modifiable lvalue
```

Comment: Use `std::string fileName;` instead.

Comment: Arrays can't be assigned to, only copied to. And if you use a fixed and static string, why use an array in the first place? Why not use the string literal directly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, you want to use an initializer-list to initialize members in a constructor:

```
canvas()
: fileName("zzz.txt")
{
}
```

When you do this:

```
fileName = "zzz.txt";
```

You are trying to assign a value to an array, which isn't legal.  You can initialize an array with values, but you can't assign it a value (as a whole) afterwards.  The initializer-list syntax allows you to initialize it with the proper value.

However, if you are using an older compiler, you may have to use `strcpy` instead:

```
strcpy(fileName,"zzz.txt");
```

For other types that can be assigned, using the initializer-list syntax isn't strictly necessary, but it is still usually a good idea.

Also, as others have noted, unless you have a good reason not to, you'd be better off using a `std::string` instead of a raw array of characters.  A `std::string` will allow for strings of arbitrary length which can be treated like regular values.

Comment: it says :  Error 2 error C2536: 'canvas::canvas::fileName' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays

Comment: @ZiaQamar: looks like you are using an older compiler.  You can use `strcpy` in that case if you don't want to switch to using `std::string`.